# Gratis Blu-ray ripper for Windows

Tags: windows, gratis, video, media-converter, ripping

I'm looking for a Blu-ray ripper for Windows that meets these requirements:

- Gratis
- Can rip any Blu-ray (with the exception of 3D Blu-ray)
- Compatible with Windows 10
- Can convert to any common video format (whether it be MKV, AVI, WMV, MP4, MOV, M4V, TiVo, MPG, FLV, etc.)

Note: XMedia Recode does *not* meet the second requirement, "XMedia Recode can only convert **unprotected Blu-rays** or DVDs".

Answer (score 2):

You're asking for a program that will do two things:

1. Decrypt Blurays and save them as files on your computer
2. Convert (re-encode) these files into a variety of different formats

I am not aware of any program that does BOTH of these things, and I am relatively confident that no such program exists. Instead, what you need are two programs: one for decryption, and one for encoding.

For step one, I recommend [MakeMKV](http://www.makemkv.com). While MakeMKV technically costs $50, it is free while in Beta, and it has been in "Beta" for more than five years, so you should be able to use it for free for the foreseeable future. Be sure to [check their forums](http://www.makemkv.com/forum2/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=1053) for the most-recent Beta key.

Of course, MakeMKV will only make, well, MKV's, which is where step 2 comes in: you need a second program--an encoder--to turn your raw MKV files into your preferred video format. I prefer to do this with a command line program called ffmpeg, but you probably want something with a GUI. Take a look at [WinFF](http://winff.org/html_new/index.html)--it seems to still be under active development (unlike SUPER), has a very simple, streamlined interface (unlike FFmpegYAG), and supports all of the older/outdated formats you listed in your question (unlike Handbreak).

Comment: Programs like this *do* exist, [here's one](http://www.acrok.com/video-converter-ultimate/), I'm just looking one that is free.

Comment: I just wanted to quickly note that I haven't used WinFF--as I said, I prefer to use ffmpeg in the command line directly. I literally found WinFF after a couple of minutes Googling for an ffmpeg wrapper. I know this is generally discouraged on SE, but in this case, I felt it was warranted because it was only a small part of my answer.

Comment: I may well be wrong about 2-in-1 programs not existing; regardless, my recommendation is that you use two separate programs, as what you're doing is essentially two separate tasks.

Comment: Also, I may be wrong about this, but looking around Acrok's site, they don't mention anything about decrypting Blurays, so I would assume it only works on unencrypted discs. Unless you're sure this isn't the case. Decrypting Blurays is not a simple task, so any program that can do it should be advertising the feature heavily.  (On a separate note, everything about that site rubs me the wrong way. They keep talking about how "fast" the converter is. Being fast is easy if you don't care about quality/size.)

Comment: I believe [it does](http://www.acrok.com/blu-ray-solutions/) but your answer should work aswell, thank you

Answer (score 1):

MakeMKV is a program for Windows, macOS, and Linux that can rip DVD and Blu-ray discs into the versatile MKV video format. There are other paid programs that offer more features, like DeUHD and AnyDVD, but we'll be using [MakeMKV Crack](https://9to5crack.com/makemkv-crack-registration-code-key/) for this tutorial, since it's free. (Technically, it's only free while in beta, but it's been "in beta" for about 10 years. You'll just need to use the latest beta key whenever it asks you to register, which is about once a month. You can purchase a license for $50 if you want to eschew this annoyance.)